How to declare a Pydantic field which content is constrained by a list that is known until execution time
I have the following Pydantic v1.10 model:
from typing import Literal

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

from connectors.snowflake.snowflake_connector import SnowflakeConnector


conversion = SnowflakeConnector().get_conversion()["conversion_name"].tolist()

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    code: int = Field(alias="Code", frozen=True)
    status: Literal["Active", "Inactive"] = Field(alias="Status")
    conversion: Literal[conversion] = Field(alias="Conversion")

Field status works perfectly, but field conversion raises this error:
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 198, in pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass.__new__
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 506, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.infer
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 436, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.__init__
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 557, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.prepare
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 831, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.populate_validators
  File "pydantic/validators.py", line 709, in find_validators
  File "pydantic/validators.py", line 473, in pydantic.validators.make_literal_validator
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

How can I achieve with field conversion what I can do with field status if I don't know the list of values until execution time?

What you've got now is the equivalent of conversion: Literal[ ["foo", "bar" ] = ...; that is, you're saying the literal value of conversion is a list, which doesn't make sense. Maybe it's easier to just write conversion: <appropriate_type> = Field(alias="Conversion"), and then use a validator to ensure correctness?

I'd recommend using StrEnum rather than Literal:
https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/types/#enums-and-choices
# from enum import StrEnum  # Python >= 3.11
from enum import Enum

class StrEnum(str, Enum): # Python < 3.11
    @staticmethod
    def _generate_next_value_(name, _, __, ___):
        return name

class Status(str, Enum):
    Active = "Active"
    Inactive = "Inactive"

# conversion = SnowflakeConnector().get_conversion()["conversion_name"].tolist()

conversion = ["a", "b", "c"]
Conversion = StrEnum("Conversion", conversion)

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    code: int = Field(alias="Code", frozen=True)
    status: Status = Field(alias="Status")
    conversion: Conversion = Field(alias="Conversion")

model = MyModel(Code=1, Status="Active", Conversion="a")

# Both of these pass, model.status and model.conversion can be used as strings.
assert isinstance(model.conversion, str)
assert model.conversion == "a"

# And this produces an error, as expected:
MyModel(Code=1, Status="Active", Conversion="d")
"""
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for MyModel
Conversion
  value is not a valid enumeration member; permitted: 'a', 'b', 'c' ...
"""


Since the list conversion is not known until execution, I would use the @validator from Pydantic. (I think it's called validator in V1. In V2 it's field_validator). For example:
from typing import Literal

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, validator

from connectors.snowflake.snowflake_connector import SnowflakeConnector


conversion = SnowflakeConnector().get_conversion()["conversion_name"].tolist()

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    code: int = Field(alias="Code", frozen=True)
    status: Literal["Active", "Inactive"] = Field(alias="Status")
    conversion: list = Field(alias="Conversion")
    
    @validator("conversion")
    def validate_conversion(cls, v):
        ...


And then your validation checks in the validate_conversion method.
